# Opentext enterprise connect edit option error

Tags: opentext, livelink

when i click the edit option in enterprise connect i am receiving the following error.

"Unable to process the response from server.Server returned: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document , and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2 Position 3."

Can you please provide the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We need to login into render settings and uncheck the Generate Weblingo Filename Comments(System Administration - Configure Rendor settings - Generate Weblingo Filename)